# Using an Array to print out a number of asterisks, dependent on number inputted from user in C

Tags: c, arrays, function

So this program should print out the number of asterisks dependending on the number you enter, so if you enter 5, the 5 asterisks will print out.

I don't know where I am going wrong? Also if anyone can recommend a good book for C, I read through my school text and C for dummies, I am just not getting it.

---

```
    void barplot(int num1, char array[]);

int main()
{
    int n1;
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d",&n1);
    printf("You have entered: %d\n",n1);

    char astrk[n1];
    strcpy(astrk, "*");

    barplot(n1, astrk);
    return(0);

}

void barplot(int num1, char array[])
{
    printf("num1=%d\n",num1);
    int i=0;


    for(i=0; i<num1; i++)
    {
        printf("%c",array[i]);
    }
}
```

Edit:   An array is needed per the assignment

Comment: Though it may be convoluted, it would _work_ if you just used `memset(astrk, '*', n1)` instead of `strcpy(astrk, "*")`...but the code really ought to be restructured.

Comment: @Richard To be sure your code is standards compliant, you should use malloc for an array whose size is determined at run time

Comment: @FUZxxl that's the problem. For some one learning a language, he should be taught the standard, which is expected to run on every compiler. Moreover, i am willing to bet that the intent of assignment was to get them to use dynamic memory allocation. I always remember having seen this as the primary use case for teaching dynamic memory i.e. allocating array of size determined at run time. Also there is a pretty good chance that it would overflow if given sufficient enough size which in case of heap would come at a far larger size.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you're stuck using an array, you can fill the `astrk` array with `'*'` characters using `memset`:

```
char astrk[n1];
memset(astrk, '*', n1);

barplot(n1, astrk);
return 0;
```

`memset` fills the array (the first argument) with copies of the character (the second argument), up to the length in the third argument. Note that this doesn't null-terminate the array, so you can't directly `printf` it.

If you do want to be able to `printf` it, then you should allocate enough space for the null terminator, like so:

```
char astrk[n1+1];
memset(astrk, '*', n1);
astrk[n1] = '\0'

printf("%s", astrk);
return 0;
```

Then you don't need the `barplot` function at all.

Comment: +1: its the dynamic array-decl sizing that is causing the head-scratches. one of occasionally handy C-only-things. nice answer.

Comment: Thanks, @WhozCraig. I'll agree, variable sized arrays are a handy feature of C99 (though they actually become an optional feature in C11, meaning you can't depend on them being available in all C11 implementations).

Comment: Oh I'm quite sure the fact you can accidentally overflow (under, actually) the stack will all-but-guarantee this is toast in C11, but man it comes in handy sometimes. I feel much more comfortable with it when the index is an unsigned char (255 max alloca). pass the wrong value for an int or size_t and kerboom ! =P

Comment: @nneonneo That is precisely the point. If you can't depend upon them, why use them? Specially i suspect the question is asked by a student so he should be taught the standards way. Not some thing that might break on some compiler and work on others

Comment: +1 You could create the array on the heap. And you could test the size variable before you allocate the memory, and then test the memory after you've created it.. Might even get extra marks for doing it that way.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need a whole `char` array just to store one character. Let's just replace the `char[]` with a single `char`:

```
void barplot(int num1, char array);

int main()
{
    int n1;
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n1);
    printf("You have entered: %d\n", n1);

    barplot(n1, '*');
    return 0;
}

void barplot(int num1, char ch)
{
    printf("num1=%d\n",num1);
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<num1; i++)
    {
        putchar(ch);
    }
}
```

Comment: oh because it an assignment that asks for it to be done with an array, thank you for taking the time to answer

Comment: In that case, you can use the (somewhat hackish) `memset` solution I mentioned in the other comment.

Comment: `printf("%c", ch)` should be replaced by `putchar(ch)`

Comment: Believe it or not, my compiler actually compiles `printf("%c", ch)` into `putchar(ch)` at `-O3`. In this case, I was just following OP's original code with some minor cleanups, but I will implement your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You did not filled your `astrk` array with asterisks. You just copied over a string literal that has only one asterisk.

If you need only to print these asterisks, why do you need an array at all?

try this:

```
void barplot(int num1)
{
    printf("num1=%d\n",num1);

    for(i=0; i<num1; i++)
    {
        printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void barplot(int num1)
{
  char s[BUFSIZ];
  memset(s,'*',BUFSIZ);
  printf("%.*s",num1%BUFSIZ,s);
}
```

Comment: This is going to be either (a) wasteful (if `BUFSIZ` is too big) or (b) wrong (if `BUFSIZ` is too small).

Comment: what is BUFSIZ, and is s just a variable?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why it has not been mentioned that standard c does not allow variable length arrays. You can do variable length arrays in C99 (ISO/IEC 9899:1999) but they are not part of C++ or standard C. It might be supported by some compilers but there is always a risk.

Besides i am certain that above question being an assignment, was given with the intention that size determined at run time should be handled using dynamic allocation such as malloc.

```
char arr[SIZE]; // size has to be a constant value or a variable with const modifier
```

Size cannot be determined at run time for the above syntax.

You should use malloc as a standard practice

```
char *arr = malloc(n1);
```

This needs to be freed latter too

```
free(arr);
```